# android studio design mode went Blank

Tags: android, android-studio

In my android project i created a custom view using canvas so that i can draw shapes
but whenever i add the custom view to my xml my design and blueprint goes blank so that nothing in the design shows.
but if i run the project the custom view works perfectly in the emulator but doesn't show on the design mode.

[image: Before adding the custom view]

[image: After adding the custom view]

Comment: Click the view options and select / unselect Show System UI or Show Tooltips. This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's major issue with Dolphin version of Android Studio .So, please wait for update in it or go for Flamingo Canary version to fix it out.

Comment: i went back to the previous version of android studio and it worked .

Answer (score 0):

**Restart android studio by clearing the cache.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Aqy.png)

Comment: I did that but the result is still the same nothing is showing

Comment: Ok. Delete entire xml code. Then check.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i did that but didn't help the problem happen to be with android studio dolphin version itself